# Access Layout Elements to the Depth of N

Tags: java, php, android

I have a pretty annoying problem here, as Im still trying to internalize each and every bits of what I am doing,

I currently have a LinearLayout, then upon onCreate of the Activity, I will populate or inflate several other LinearLayout's with Buttons, my problem is that when I try to access the button, it seems that I'm not getting any close or deeper from the LinearLayout, all I can get is the LinearLayout(Parent) and the other LinearLayout(Children), I believe there is a way, Im just totally confused how to do it.

```
LinearLayout
 ->LinearLayout(Child1)->Button1, Button2, Button3
 ->LinearLayout(Child2)->Button4, Button5, Button6
```

How would I be able to access and get the Buttons?

My source;

```
for (int x=0; x<ll.getChildCount(); x++){
  View v = ll.getChildAt(x);
  Class c = v.getClass();
  if(c == LinearLayout.class){
    for(int y=0; y< ; y++){
      **I know there is something that must be done here, likewise, is this the most
      efficient way of doing things?
    }
  }
 Log.i("test", c.getName());
}
```

Only the LinearLayout(Parent) exist in the XML, others are inflated run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply cast `v` to a `LinearLayout`, then access its children just like you did with its parent. Something like:

```
for (int x=0; x<ll.getChildCount(); x++){
  View v = ll.getChildAt(x);
  Class c = v.getClass();
  if(c == LinearLayout.class){
    //Cast to LinearLayout since View doesn't expose a way to access children
    LinearLayout innerLayout = (LinearLayout)v;
    for(int y=0; y<innerLayout.getChildCount() ; y++){
      Button b = (Button)innerLayout.getChildAt(y);

      //Do something with b
    }
  }
 Log.i("test", c.getName());
}
```

Depending on your exact hierarchy you could possibly simplify this by removing the reflection and simply doing a null check (if needed, wrap it in a try/catch and catch a `ClassCastException`). I've typically done something like this in situations where I need to traverse a layout tree that's dynamically generated:

```
for (int i = 0; i < outerLayout.getChildCount(); ++i)
{
    try
    {
        LinearLayout innerLayout = (LinearLayout)outerLayout.getChildAt(i);

        if (innerLayout != null)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < innerLayout.getChildCount(); ++j)
            {
                Button btn = (Button)innerLayout.getChildAt(j);

                //Do something with btn
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ClassCastException cEx)
    {
        Log.w("WARN", "Unexpected child type in outerLayout. " + cEx.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is an untested example (could need better exception handling depending on your requirements and layouts) but hopefully it gives you the general idea. If you want to be a little bit more type-agnostic you could also use a cast to [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) instead. That would allow you to potentially use different kinds of layout containers as children, if needed, as they are subclasses of `ViewGroup` (which is where they inherit `getChildAt()` and `getChildCount()` from).